# How to declare multiple permissions in the Android manifest file service tag

Tags: android

```
 <service
        android:name=".JobSchedulerService2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    </service>
```

I need  declaration "android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" and "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" multiple permission.

I'm sorry, my English is not good.

Comment: Please refer this for your answer. [1] http://stackoverflow.com/a/5439320/6096821

Comment: Why do you think that your `<service>` needs `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"`? That states that whatever component wants to work with your service needs to hold that permission. What evidence do you have that every Android 5.0+ device is set up that way?

Comment: JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        JobInfo.Builder builder2= new JobInfo.Builder( 1,
                new ComponentName( getPackageName(),
                        JobSchedulerService2.class.getName() ) );
        builder2.setPeriodic(10);
        //setPersisted need declaration RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in service tag 
//        builder2.setPersisted(true);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder2.build());

Comment: Thank you谢谢大家很喜欢这个社区,我会学习好英语的,谢谢国外网友
Love this community, I will learn English well, thank you, foreign users